# How to allow users to run a function, but not access objects the function is accessing

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, permissions, plpgsql

I have a PL/PgSQL stored procedure that performs various operations on tables (`SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, TRUNCATE`).

I want users to be able to run the stored procedure, but not themselves perform those same operations on the tables.

Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps this answer by Erwin Brandstetter will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867175/postgresql-db-user-should-only-be-allowed-to-call-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's possible. Create the function with the user owning all those tables and use the `SECURITY DEFINER` modifier.

> *SECURITY DEFINER specifies that the function is to be executed with the privileges of the user that created it.*

```
create or replace function foo()
  returns void
as
$body$
...
$body$
language plpgsql
security definer;
```

Also see the example in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY